# Question about Galilean relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, galilean-relativity

If a boat is moving at constant speed relative to water, on a trip between two cities, the ride upstream lasts $t_1=6~h$ and the ride downstream lasts $t_2=3~h$. What time ($t'$) will the boat need to finish the ride downstream with its engines turned off.

The answer is $$t'=\frac{2t_1t_2}{t_1-t_2}=12~h$$ but I can't get this result. I've obtained following equations $$t_1+t_2=\frac{v_{river}}{v_{boat}-v_{river}}2t_2$$ and $$t_1+t'=(t_1+t_2)\frac{d}{2v_{river}t_2}$$ but I can't find a way of eliminating the necessary terms to obtain the correct expression for time.

Comment: I'm really tired of this lasting trend of this forum that homework questions face excessive scrutiny. Some people are trying to study and can't get help from other places, so it would be nice for everyone to have that in mind next time they see a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to realize that the distance always remains the same.

So $$x=v_{1}t_{1}=v_{2}t_{2}=v_{3}t_{3}$$

Where:

$$v_{1}=v_{boat}-v_{river}$$

$$v_{2}=v_{boat}+v_{river}$$

$$v_{3}=v_{river}$$

So taking the three possible combinations we obtain 3 equations of 3 variables: $$t_{3},v_{boat},v_{river}$$

Solve them to obtain the correct result.

(I've switched $t`\rightarrow t_{3}$ for convenience)

Comment: Thank you. However I find it counter intuitive that the trip downstream lasts longer than the trip upstream, even though the trip downstream is made with rivers velocity alone.

Comment: @ahra The reason the downstream trip is longer is just the numbers the question writer chose. It will be the same equations anyway.